# How shoud I put a condition correlated with the select option value

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I'm writing a code which reads a drop down value then perform some actions, and I try to figure out how to get the select option value and put a condition regarding to that one.

```
<script>
        var e = document.getElementById("selectNewBalance");
        var value = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;
       if (value == "Inserted values"){

/// from here to the return statement I know for sure it works but now i'm trying to apply this condition only when the select option is  "Inserted values"
        var checkThisOnes = ["Value1", "Value2", "Value3"];
       var printThisOnes = []
       var message = "Please fill these fields: "
        $('#myform').submit(function() {
            var result=true;
            for (i = 0; i < checkThisOnes.length; i = i + 1) {
                var checkedValue = $('#'+checkThisOnes[i]).val();
                if (checkedValue === undefined || checkedValue === "") {
                    message = message + checkThisOnes[i]+ ", ";
                    result =false;
                }
            }
            if (result === false) {
            alert(message)
            location.reload();}
            return result;
        });}
</script>
```

Comment: Can you share your HTML and more detailed description of your problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading the value from a dropdown is easier than how you did it:

```js
var select = document.getElementById("selectNewBalance");

// add an event listener to the element
select.addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  if (e.target.value === 'Inserted values') {
    console.log('You can do something here')
  }
})
```

```html
<select id="selectNewBalance">
  <option selected disabled>--</option>
  <option value="Inserted values">Inserted values</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

With jQuery the snippet looks like:

```js
jQuery('document').ready(function($) {
  $('#selectNewBalance').on('change', function(e) {
    if ($(this).val() === 'Inserted values') {
      console.log('You can do something here')
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select id="selectNewBalance">
  <option selected disabled>--</option>
  <option value="Inserted values">Inserted values</option>
  <option value="Other">Other</option>
</select>
```

That is all. The point is, you need to place your conditions in an event, like `change`, so it runs when the input value changes.